# Why Cant I see PostgreSQL 9.5 in pgAdmin on windows 10?

Tags: postgresql

Any idea why I can't see my local PostgreSQL 9.5 in pgAdmin on Windows 10?
I did install postgres and I see the service running, but pgAdmin III doesn't show anything in server groups.

I can run it from the terminal.

Comment: Did you add a connection? https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.22/connect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not add any server connection automatically - do it yourself.

[image]